# Can I 3d photoscan with blender?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, image

I have tried 3d photoscanning with alot of different programs like meshroom or agisoft metashape pro but didn't get what I wanted.
Is there anyway to 3d photoscan images in blender?
I think that'd be easier to me because I am used to blender more.
If you know please consider to tell me how to do that or just send a link

Comment: There are some experiments people have done in Blender, but Meshroom and Agisoft Photoscan / Metashape are more suitable solutions. If you're not getting good results with them, then the issue is likely somewhere else, e.g. inconsistent lighting in your photos, not enough coverage, changing focal length, ...

Comment: In meshroom it kept giving a message the alice_vision_depth map has stopped working whenever I reach the depth map node

Comment: No there are no photoscan tools with blender. At least nothing automatic or remotely close to Meshroom or Photoscan. For help with other pieces of software use their own support forums or groups.

Comment: ok thank you for your help